# Strange JSON Format - What would be best handling?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, deserialization

I'm fairly new to rest apis and tried to follow some simple tutorials. Using some test Uri's I get
a response for a server-object that looks like this:

```
{
  "server": {
    "id": 123456,
    "name": "srv-ubuntu-01",
    "status": "running",
    "created": "2021-01-11T13:04:24+00:00"
  }
}
```

Usually I'd be able to deserialize this using NewtonSoft.Json with

```
var server = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<XServer>(jsonString);
```

using given class:

```
public class XServer
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public String Name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("status")]
    public String Status { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("created")]
    public DateTime DateCreate { get; set; }
}
```

However, in this case this doesen't work because the json response from the server holds the server object as a "sub-object" ((?) I don't know the correct term). So I figured I could use following code as a workaround:

```
var def = new { server = new Object() };
var defObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(jsonString, def);
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<XServer>(defObj.server.ToString());
```

But that can't be it, right? Obviously there is something I'm missing... at least I think so. Any input is appreciated, as mentioned, I'm a beginner, eager to learn ;)

Comment: You just need a wrapper object, one with a `server` property of type `XServer`.

Comment: To go deeper on @madreflection's comment.  Note that your JSON looks like `{"server": { /* your XServer class */} }`.  The result is that you are deserializing an object with a single property named `server`, whose value is an object of your `XServer` type.

Comment: @madreflection if I understand you correctly, that's exactly what I did with my custom definition... right? Edit: nope, understood, sorry

Comment: You are allowed and encouraged to answer you own question, move your solution into an answer

Comment: @Charlieface thanks for the heads up :) done

Comment: @arvenyon https://app.quicktype.io/ will be useful

Comment: @Genusatplay that is actually a morbidly good tool. Thanks a lot for the recommendation!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Root Object has the key, `server` which has the object `XServer`.

Deserialize to RootObject to access the server object, 'XServer'.

```
public class RootObject {
  [JsonProperty("server")]
  public XServer Server {get; set;}
}

var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonString);
XServer server = obj.Server;
```

Answer (score 0):

=========== Solution ===========

So using @madreflections input I came to following solution, which works perfectly fine:

```
public class XServerRootObject
{ 
    [JsonProperty("server")]
    public XServer Server { get; set; }
}

public class XServer
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public String Name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("status")]
    public String Status { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("created")]
    public DateTime DateCreate { get; set; }
}
```

Using the root object as following:

```
public XServer GetServer(int id)
{
    var req = new RestRequest("/servers/" + id, Method.GET, DataFormat.Json);
    req.AddHeader("authorization", "Bearer " + _token);
    var json = _client.Get(req).Content;
    var srvRoot = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<XServerRootObject>(json);
    return srvRoot.Server;
}
```